# How to fix my python code that parses body text from website?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a program that parses the body text from each article on each page of this news website's archive. Initially, my program stopped at line 32 and I printed each link and saved them to a csv file and that worked. Now I want to open up each link and save the body text of the article to a csv file. I tried doing the same code format as I did initially in terms of using BeautifulSoup but now my code doesn't print anything. I don't know if my issue is with how I'm using BeautifulSoup or how I wrote the tags from the HTML of the website. Here is the archive website: https://www.politico.com/newsletters/playbook/archive (there are 408 pages on it)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

csvFile = 'C:/Users/k/Dropbox/Politico/pol.csv'
with open(csvFile, mode='w') as pol:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(pol, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    #for each page on Politico archive
    for p in range(0,409):
        url = urlopen("https://www.politico.com/newsletters/playbook/archive/%d" % p)
        content = url.read()

        #Parse article links from page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
        articleLinks = soup.findAll('article', attrs={'class':'story-frag format-l'})

        #Each article link on page
        for article in articleLinks:
            link = article.find('a', attrs={'target':'_top'}).get('href')

            #Open and read each article link
            articleURL = urlopen(link)
            articleContent = articleURL.read()

            #Parse body text from article page
            soupArticle = BeautifulSoup(articleContent, "lxml")

            #Limits to div class = story-text tag (where article text is)
            articleText = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'story-text'})
            for div in articleText:
                #Limits to b tag (where the body text seems so exclusively be)
                bodyText = div.find('b')
                print(bodyText)

                #Adds article link to csv file
                csvwriter.writerow([bodyText])
```

I expect the output to print the body text of each article on the archive and save it all to a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not printing anything because you are looking in the wrong spot at `articleText = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'story-text'})`

You stored that as `soupArticle`, not `soup`.

Also did you want the text or the html element? As is, you are getting the tag/element. If you want just the text, you'd need `bodyText = div.find('b').text`

But the main issue is you want to change:

`articleText = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'story-text'})`

to

`articleText = soupArticle.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'story-text'})`

To get the full article you'll have to loop through the `p` tags. And figure out how to skip the parts you don't want. There a better way of doing it, but to get you going, something like this:

```
for article in articleLinks:
    link = article.find('a', attrs={'target':'_top'}).get('href')

     articleURL = urlopen(link)
     articleContent = articleURL.read()

     soupArticle = BeautifulSoup(articleContent, "lxml")
     articleText = soupArticle.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'story-text'})

     for div in articleText:
        bodyText = div.find_all('p')
        for para in bodyText:
            if 'By ' in para.text:
                continue
            print (para.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake on the soupArticle vs soup part. That makes sense to me. For the text part, I just want the text, not the html element. So, I tried out your suggestion and it only prints out the bolded intro to each paragraph. I'm trying to print the whole article, bolded and non-bolded parts. This is definitely putting me in the right direction though. I tried div.find('p').text since all the article seems to be in the p class but that included stuff I didn't want to print like the author's names. Do you know how I could fix this to just be the article text? Thanks!

Comment: @kittykat14 I added a bit more to the solution above. Also if the solution is helpful, be sure to accept it.